# north of east vs east of north in vector

Tags: vectors

When we say $20°$ northeast does it mean $20°$ north of east or $20°$ east of north in vectors? I see that the meaning of north of east is the x-axis will be the reference axis and for east of north the y-axis will be the reference axis but I'm confuse when we say northeast.

Comment: The 20deg would be in absolute (ie cw from 0) the northeast is just a reminder about which general quadrant that is in. I'm not sure this is really physics

Comment: What is cw? clockwise?

Comment: @MartinBeckett Although that does make sense some sense, it depends on the standards they used when they came up with their naming system.  For example, your interpretation of "20° Northeast" doesn't make a lot of sense in the traditional unit circle, where "20°" is still Northeast; but it is actually going counterclockwise starting on the horizontal, not clockwise starting on the vertical.  So I still don't think this is a physics question as much as a "what format are we using?", which we obviously can't answer.  I'd suggest asking your teacher/professor what they prefer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be about a specific coordinate convention (that we have no details about); not a physical concept.

Comment: @JMac I assumed the question came from something outside physics. eg in air traffic control you might say "turn right onto bearing 090" (to a plane heading North).  The "right" doesn't specify the convention it just adds a safety margin to ensure you understood. If ATC said turn left onto 090 you would assume you had misheard.

Comment: @MartinBeckett The problem is, we don't know if this is an ATC type example, if this is an exercise on the unit circle with terms like "North, South, East and West" added to make it feel more familiar, etc.  I wont argue that your interpretation is 95% likely to be the right one.  The point being when "we" say 20° Northeast, what we mean by it depends entirely on who _"we" are_, which we don't know.